# How to properly print out/sort binary file data read into an array using fread

Tags: c, printing, virtual-machine, endianness

At the moment i am at the very starts of writing a simple VM in C and am stuck on perhaps the easiest part as after this it all would make sense. I am attempting to read in the `input.bin` binary file given below into my global `memory` array and then once i have read that data in to then do processing on that data. Given my current code below i am getting the data output but not in a correct way that holds form to the way that it should be being input, is there a way to specifically input data in `big-endian` format? 
I am checking the contents of my `input.bin` file with the command `od -x --endian=big input.bin | head -5`

**MAIN.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXMEM 1024

unsigned memory[MAXMEM];

size_t loads(char *filename)
{
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if(!file){
    perror("Failed to read file");
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE);
    return fread(memory, sizeof *memory, MAXMEM, file);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    if(argc <= 1){
        printf("No file Found\n");
        return -1;
        }
    char *filename = argv[1];
    loads(filename);
    printf("%02x %02x\n", memory[0], memory[1]);
}
```

**INPUT.bin**

```
b10a b200 1123
```

**CURRENT OUTPUT**

```
b20ab1 2311
```

**Desired Output**

```
b10a b200 1123
OR
b1 0a b2 00 11 23
```

Comment: Then print the output byte by byte, not by using `int`s.

Comment: care to elaborate?

Comment: `unsigned` is a short variant for `unsigned int`, and the last 25 years or so `int` have been a 32-bit type. If you want to print bytes, then why not use an array of bytes instead? As in `uint8_t memory[MAXMEM]`. Then you can simply print it using the `hh` format specifier prefix (to tell `printf` that the data is a bytes), as in `printf("%02hhx %02hhx\n", memory[0], memory[1] )`.

Comment: Regarding the endianness issue, you first of all need to be certain of the endianness of the data in the file, then it's just a matter of presenting the bytes in the correct order.

Comment: In all honesty the use of the unsigned int array was due to given instruction on this project. Changing that could perhaps be an issue but i can see why it would be redundant. The purpose of this is to read this data in and be able to process instructions and in a sense emulate a cpu

Comment: When reading the data in the file in big endian format it is output correctly 100% of the time no matter the instruction so thats why my thought process went to "is it possible to write the data to the array in big endian format"